# Updating record from Vue.js to Laravel

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.6

How can I update a record from Vue.js to Laravel ?

I am trying to send AJAX request from vue like below

```
var address_data = {
                    name        :this.dname,                    
                    address     :this.address,
                    telephone_no:this.telephone_no,
                    email       :this.email,
                    image       :this.image,
                    user_id     :this.user_id,
                }

this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/{address}',address_data,{headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.$auth.getToken()}}).then(response => {
                    if(response) {                      
                            //some code
                        }
                    },
                    response => {
                        //some code
                    })
```

In `api.php` my route is like below

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'addresses', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::put('/{address}', 'AddressController@update');
});
```

In `AddressContoller.php` I wrote below code for `update` function.

```
public function update(Request $request, Address $address)
    {
        $address->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($address, 200);
    }
```

May be I did some mistake. I don't know where is the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the problems there is that it won't find a route and methods. You have multiple problems there:

1. Javascript won't make interpolation with normal `'` , you need to use ``, so your code sends request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/{address}` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/2` for example
2. On the code you showed us, "`address`" is not defined
3. You are making a request with `.post` but on laravel you defined the route as a `put`.